# Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, python-requests

I created a simple python app that has a client part that accesses (uses the requests library) another app (api app) using Flask library to get data. Everything works when I run it locally.I run the api app and then tried running the client  in my post request to get data format json from file format xml :

response = requests.post("https://appapi90.azurewebsites.net:5050/files/result.xml")

The error I am getting is:

> requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='appapi90.azurewebsites.net', port=5050): Max retries exceeded with url: /files/result.xml (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000227088081F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))

and this is my code

```
import requests
import os

UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "upload"
API_URL = 'https://appapi90.azurewebsites.net:5050'

if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY)

with open('result.xml') as file:
    content = file.read()

response = requests.post('{}/files/result.xml'.format(API_URL), data=content )

def download_url(url):
    #print("downloading: ", url)
    # assumes that the last segment after the / represents the file name
    # if url is abc/xyz/file.txt, the file name will be file.txt
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("/") + 1
    file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]
    pathfile = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, file_name)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(pathfile, 'wb') as f:
            for data in r:
                f.write(data)

# download a sngle url
# the file name at the end is used as the local file name
download_url("{}/data.json".format(API_URL))
download_url("{}/data.csv".format(API_URL))


# print json content
print(response)
```

Comment: the host you try to run the script is not able to access the the url and then, you get the WinError 10060 .. First thing to check would be to use telnet to verify that you can establish a connection: `telnet appapi90.azurewebsites.net 5050`  - if that fails, so will your python code. Maybe the host you executes is behind a proxy and doesnt allow direct connections to the internet ?

Comment: hey @rasjani that's what i get when i use telnet  **Connecting To appapi90.azurewebsites.net...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5050: Connect failed**

Comment: so the host you are trying to run on, does not have connection to internet or requires a proxy .. Talk you your sysadmin ?

Comment: it's an app service in azure it does have connection to internet and do not  require a proxy @rasjani

Comment: It can be firewall on either side, routing  or what not. What i'm saying: if you cannot telnet from the host you try to run your python code  - the issue is something you cant solve in the code and you should talk to whomever is maintaining your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using FastAPI/uvicorn Python web app then use the below
  startup command: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
  application:app

- If you are using Flask Python web app then use the below startup
  command: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app

You tried and confirmed that with the above flask startup command it fixed your issue.

Since we have automatic port detection. Only Azure web app for containers you can specify an app setting called WEBSITES_PORT and give it the value of the expected port number. This is only used to EXPOSE the Port internally to your docker container but publicly to expose port is not possible and it will be 80/443 only. The Azure App Service is PaaS offering and opening of other ports are not allowed.